# Como migrar una Base de Datos Mysql a Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, wordpress

Muy buenas colegas, quiero recurrir a ustedes para ver si me pueden dar luces en este panorama oscuro para mi.

Un Cliente tiene un sitio web hecho en PHP, para que tengan una idea, trata sobre ofertas de empleos temporales. Por tanto tiene su Base de Datos, y toda su estructura que puedan imaginar. Ok.

Aparte se le ofrece un Wordpress con las funciones de oferta de empleo, una conexion con api de scoptalent, el tema los plugins y todo eso. Ok

A pesar de lo loco que suene todo esto, migran su pagina a este Wordpress, ahora esta el detalle, sus usuarios deben de poder migrarse y conectarse al Wordpress, este nuevo sitio. El usuario en el sitio anterior ya tienen todos sus registros, curriculum montado, configuraciones y de mas, muchas no existen en Wordpress.

Diganme ud. como migrar estos usuarios de esta web ahora en Wordpress que obviamente tienen tablas y registros con nombres distintos y de mas.

Esto para mi es O.O

Comment: O es que yo me estoy enrollando (liando) mucho XD.

Comment: Pues un poco te has liado, por no decir bastante. No sé si sabes que WP trabaja con tablas. Entonces, puedes migrar esas tablas y seguirlas usando en WP. No veo cuál es el problema. Tampoco tienes que dejar que los usuarios se migren por su cuenta (creo yo). Si eres el programador del sitio, lo que tienes que hacer es migrar todo, adaptar todo al nuevo sitio y hacerlo funcional para los usuarios reutilizando las tablas o la info que hay en ellas. A lo sumo, lo único que va a cambiar serían cosas como la URL. Y hasta puedes aprovechar para modernizar todo y hacer las URLs más amigables, etc.

Comment: Osea que tengo que hacer la migración del Usuario uno a uno. Por que parte de la Data tendría que dividirla en distintas tablas que ya están en Wordpress, sabes que  Wordpress tiene su tabla de usuario, y de paso los plugins tienen sus tablas aparte (algunos).

Comment: No he dicho que tenga que ser uno a uno. Puedes hacer una copia de seguridad de tus tablas en el sitio anterior y volcarlas en la nueva base de datos de WP. Todo lo demás nadie te puede decir cómo hacerlo, porque eso depende de la naturaleza de tu sitio: ¿volcar todo en nuevas tablas o reutilizar las viejas?, etc. No sé a qué te refieres con lo de los plugin, parece como si se tratase de algo como microsites (¿cada usuario tiene su micrositio con plugin propios o compartirían toda la estructura del nuevo WP?). O sea, son mil preguntas que puedes resolver una vez entiendas como funciona WP.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes migrar los datos de usuario, pero recomiendo no migrar las contraseñas, lo mejor es que hagas así:

1. Crees una pagina en Wordpress que se encargue de hacer la migración, que pida los datos del usuario, nombre o email y contraseña
2. Esta pagina valide con la base de datos de la pagina de PHP que la info sea correcta
3. Por medio de codigo de Wordpress crees el usuario en la base de datos, con la misma contraseña suministrada por el usuario en el paso 1
4. Migres todos los demás datos relevantes desde la base de datos de PHP hacia la de Wordpress.